# do_POST method failing in Python 3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x, multipartform-data, python-3.6

I have been trying to make a basic multi-part form in Python 3.6. The do_GET method is working perfectly, but the do_POST method keeps failing.

When I submit the form in Chrome, it says that **localhost didn’t send any data.
ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE**, but when I check the Network tab in the Developer Console, I can see the form values.

The code seems to be working perfectly with Python 2.7. I am not sure with where I went wrong in the code.

Here's the code I wrote:

```
from http.server import BaseHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPServer
import cgi


class WebServerHandle(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self):
        try:
            if self.path.endswith("/new"):
                self.send_response(200)
                self.send_header('Content-type', 'text/html')
                self.end_headers()
                output = ""
                output += "<html><head><style>body {font-family: Helvetica, Arial; color: #333}</style></head>"
                output += "<body><h2>Add new Restaurant</h2>"
                output += "<form method='POST' enctype='multipart/form-data' action='/new'>"
                output += "<input name='newRestaurantName' type='text' placeholder='New Restaurant Name'> "
                output += "<input type='submit' value='Add Restaurant'>"
                output += "</form></html></body>"
                self.wfile.write(bytes(output, "utf-8"))
                return
            if self.path.endswith("/restaurant"):
                self.send_response(200)
                self.send_header('Content-type', 'text/html')
                self.end_headers()
                output = ""
                output += "<html><head><style>body {font-family: Helvetica, Arial; color: #333}</style></head>"
                output += "<body><h3>Restaurant name added successfully!</h3>"
                output += "</html></body>"
                self.wfile.write(bytes(output, "utf-8"))
                return
        except IOError:
            self.send_error(404, 'File Not Found: %s' % self.path)

    def do_POST(self):
        try:
            if self.path.endswith("/new"):
                ctype, pdict = cgi.parse_header(self.headers.getheader('content-type'))
                if ctype == 'multipart/form-data':
                    fields = cgi.parse_multipart(self.rfile, pdict)
                    restaurant_name = fields.get('newRestaurantName')
                    print("Restaurant name is ", restaurant_name)
                    self.send_response(301)
                    self.send_header('Content-type', 'text/html')
                    self.send_header('Location', '/restaurant')
                    self.end_headers()
        except:
            print("Something went wrong, inside exception..")


def main():
    try:
        server = HTTPServer(('', 8080), WebServerHandle)
        print("Starting web server on the port 8080..")
        server.serve_forever()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print('^C entered. Shutting down the server..')
        server.socket.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: If you remove the `try/except` in the `do_POST` method, you'll see that this is the same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31486618/cgi-parse-multipart-function-throws-typeerror-in-python-3

Comment: Possible duplicate of [cgi.parse\_multipart function throws TypeError in Python 3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31486618/cgi-parse-multipart-function-throws-typeerror-in-python-3)

Comment: @snakecharmerb The code directly doesn't seem to be working, but I need to decode the field values to `utf-8` whenever I get the field values, then its working even with the try catch block.

Comment: The purpose of removing the `try/except` block is so that the actual error message is displayed in the console.  Then it's easy to google the error message yourself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Made a change to decode to the field values from the form.

Changed the `self.headers.getheader('content-type')` method to

`self.headers.('content-type')`.

Then added the following line after that, to decode the `pdict` value:

`pdict['boundary'] = bytes(pdict['boundary'], "utf-8")`,

and then to print the field values by converting from bytes to string, I changed the `print` line to

`print("Restaurant name is ", restaurant_name[0].decode("utf-8"))`.

So the final code looks like:

```
    def do_POST(self):
        try:
            if self.path.endswith("/new"):
                ctype, pdict = cgi.parse_header(self.headers['content-type'])
                pdict['boundary'] = bytes(pdict['boundary'], "utf-8")
                if ctype == 'multipart/form-data':
                    fields = cgi.parse_multipart(self.rfile, pdict)
                    print("Fields value is", fields)
                    restaurant_name = fields.get('newRestaurantName')
                    print("Restaurant name is ", restaurant_name[0].decode("utf-8"))
                    self.send_response(301)
                    self.send_header('Content-type', 'text/html')
                    self.send_header('Location', '/restaurant')
                    self.end_headers()
        except:
            print("Inside the exception block")
```

Answer (score 1):

When I run your final code, the same problem happens again "localhost didn't send any data".

You have to add `content_len = int(self.headers.get('Content-length'))` below
`ctype, pdict = cgi.parse_header(self.headers['content-type'])`. Then, you need to add `pdict['CONTENT-LENGTH'] = content_len` below `pdict['boundary'] = bytes(pdict['boundary'], "utf-8")`. There is also an indentation error.

Final code:

```
from http.server import BaseHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPServer
import cgi


class WebServerHandle(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self):
        try:
            if self.path.endswith("/new"):
                self.send_response(200)
                self.send_header('Content-type', 'text/html')
                self.end_headers()
                output = ""
                output += "<html><head><style>body {font-family: Helvetica, Arial; color: #333}</style></head>"
                output += "<body><h2>Add new Restaurant</h2>"
                output += "<form method='POST' enctype='multipart/form-data' action='/new'>"
                output += "<input name='newRestaurantName' type='text' placeholder='New Restaurant Name'> "
                output += "<input type='submit' value='Add Restaurant'>"
                output += "</form></html></body>"
                self.wfile.write(bytes(output, "utf-8"))
                return
            if self.path.endswith("/restaurant"):
                self.send_response(200)
                self.send_header('Content-type', 'text/html')
                self.end_headers()
                output = ""
                output += "<html><head><style>body {font-family: Helvetica, Arial; color: #333}</style></head>"
                output += "<body><h3>Restaurant name added successfully!</h3>"
                output += "</html></body>"
                self.wfile.write(bytes(output, "utf-8"))
                return
        except IOError:
            self.send_error(404, 'File Not Found: %s' % self.path)

    def do_POST(self):
        try:
            if self.path.endswith("/new"):
                ctype, pdict = cgi.parse_header(self.headers['content-type'])
                content_len = int(self.headers.get('Content-length'))
                pdict['boundary'] = bytes(pdict['boundary'], "utf-8")
                pdict['CONTENT-LENGTH'] = content_len
                if ctype == 'multipart/form-data':
                    fields = cgi.parse_multipart(self.rfile, pdict)
                    print("Fields value is", fields)
                    restaurant_name = fields.get('newRestaurantName')
                self.send_response(301)
                self.send_header('Content-type', 'text/html')
                self.send_header('Location', '/restaurant')
                self.end_headers()

        except:
            print("Inside the exception block")


def main():
    try:
        server = HTTPServer(('', 8080), WebServerHandle)
        print("Starting web server on the port 8080..")
        server.serve_forever()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print('^C entered. Shutting down the server..')
        server.socket.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```