# HTTP web server POST returning blank page (Python)

Tags: python, http, server

I have been facing some difficulty for the better part of today and I finally decided to come over to this fantastic community for help.

I am learning full-stack principles using Python. My issue is creating working with a HTTP server. The idea is to have an 'echo page', meaning, there is a `HTML input` field, and any text submitted through this field is echoed back.

The `HTML input` field is rendered by the server's **`do_GET`**, and an echo page is returned using the server's **`do_POST`**

Following a tutorial on the principles of HTTP, here is some code I wrote to execute a `do_GET` using Python's **`http.server`** module. (I must add that I am using Python 3.9, and I learned that I had to change the imported modules from this:

```
from BaseHTTPServer import BaseHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPServer
```

to this:

```
from http.server import BaseHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPServer
```

I also leaned that using version 3.X of Python, I needed to `encode()` the `wfile.write()` content. These are the tweaks that allowed the **`do_GET`** method to work.

Here is my full script:

```
import cgi
from http.server import BaseHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPServer


class serverHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
 def do_GET(self):
     if self.path.endswith('/hello'):
         self.send_response(200)
         self.send_header('Content-type', 'text/html')
         self.end_headers()

         output = ""
         output += "<html><body> Hey There!"
         output += "<form method='POST' enctype='multipart/form-data' action='/hello'>"
         output += "<h2> What would you like me to say?</h2>"
         output += "<input name = 'message' type = 'text' />"
         output += "<input type = 'submit' value = 'Submit'/>"
         output += "</form>"

         output += "</body></html>"
         # must encode for python 3+
         self.wfile.write(output.encode())
         print(output)
         return
     else:
         self.send_error(404, 'File not found: {}'.format(self.path))

 def do_POST(self):
     try:
         self.send_response(301)
         self.send_header('Content-type', 'text/html')
         self.end_headers()
         message_content = None
         param_dict = None
         content_type, param_dict = cgi.parse_header(
             self.headers.getheader('content-type'))
         if content_type == 'multipart/form-data':
             fields = cgi.parse_multipart(self.rfile, param_dict)
             message_content = fields.get('message')
         output = ''
         output += '<html><body>'
         output += '<h2> You Said: </h2>'
         output += '<h1> %s </h1>' % message_content[0]
         output += "<form method='POST' enctype='multipart/form-data' action='/hello'>"
         output += "<h2> What would you like me to say?</h2>"
         output += "<input name = 'message' type = 'text' />"
         output += "<input type = 'submit' value = 'Submit'/>"
         output += "</form>"
         output += '</body></html>'
         self.wfile.write(output.encode())
         print(output)

     except:
         pass


def main():
 server = None
 try:
     port = 8080
     server = HTTPServer(('', port), serverHandler)
     print('Server running on port {}'.format(port))
     server.serve_forever()
 except KeyboardInterrupt:
     print('Server shutting down...')
     server.socket.close()


main()
```

As expected, the server runs on port 8080 as specified in the `main` function. In the `serverHandler` class, I specified a `\hello` path, on which the page with the HTML `input` field is rendered.

The problem comes in when I type in text to the input field and click on the `submit` button.

Ideally, the page returned from `do_POST` should have a HTML **`h2`** element that displays the text that was keyed in on submit, and below it, a blank `input` field should be shown to allow for new text to be entered and echoed.

This however, as I have mentioned, does not happen, and I instead see a **blank page** on my browser upon clicking the `submit` button.

Here is the terminal output when the script is run:

```
Anthony ~\..\digitization\back-end git: Development ≣ +1 ~1 -0 ! ❯❯❯ python .\webserver.py

Server running on port 8080
127.0.0.1 - - [28/Dec/2020 21:12:36] "GET /hello HTTP/1.1" 200 -
<html><body> Hey There!<form method='POST' enctype='multipart/form-data' action='/hello'><h2> What would you like me to say?</h2><input name = 'message' type = 'text' /><input type = 'submit' value = 'Submit'/></form></body></html>
127.0.0.1 - - [28/Dec/2020 21:12:42] "POST /hello HTTP/1.1" 301 -
```

There seems to be something off with my `do_POST` method.

As mentioned, I am in the process of learning, and the original script was written in Python 2.X [linked here.](https://github.com/udacity/Full-Stack-Foundations/blob/master/Lesson-2/post-web-server/webserver.py)

I will appreciate insights on what is happening, and a solution to get round it.
Thank you in advance

:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dug a little deeper into the community and found a workaround that proved to solve my particular issue.

Kindly note that [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32437172/9816248) worked in my scenario, however if it doesn't work for you, you could follow the thread and try out the various suggestions outlined.

:)